# Pulling Partials with onclick function in Javascript function (Ruby on rails)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

This code that I am using to pull a partial from Calendar/_form.html.erb is rendering the partial before I click on the actual button. Is there a more efficient way to do this? It's also not pulling any css/js correctly either.

```
<div id="demo">
    This Will Magically Change to the partial i am rendering!
</div>

<button onclick="myFunction()"> Switch to partial button </button>

<script>
  function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById ("demo").src = <%= render 'calendars/form' %>;
  }
</script>
```

For some reason I'm starting to think that this method of pulling data or partials isn't the right way (angularjs seems to do it in a diff way to create Single Page Application for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a separate route in routes file.

Then modify the below one

```
<button onclick="myFunction()"> Switch to partial button </button>
```

to

```
<%= link_to "Switch to partial button", calender_path, :remote => true %>
```

In your controller, add the below method.

```
def calender
  respond_to do |format|               
    format.js
  end        
end
```

Then you should create the `calender.js.erb` in your correct directory and add the following code in that file.

```
$('#demo').html("<%= render :partial => 'form' %>");
```

Ref: [Tutorial](https://blog.codeship.com/unobtrusive-javascript-via-ajax-rails/)